# Aweber Wordpress Widget Wont work

Tags: php, wordpress, aweber

Im using the Aweber Wordpress plugin and every time I try to hit the submit button on the form, all it does is refresh the page without actually submitting. The form is supposed to behave like this:

http://forms.aweber.com/form/01/2069621401.html

however, when you check the form on my site, which is here:

http://acnecuresite.com

you will see what im talking about.

Can anyone help me fix this thing? It has to be in the widge

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it you're not wrapping your form propery with the `<form>` wrapper. Try wrapping your form on the widget properly so it includes its proper markup, i.e.

```
<form action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl" class="af-form-wrapper" method="post">
....
</form>
```

Comment: Im sorry but i dont think thats not it...The widget already has the code written correctly as far as the opening and closing form tags

Comment: If you look closely at the source of your webpage the form is not coming up... Screenshot from yor main site: http://i.imgur.com/uIyov.jpg ..screenshot from your demo page: http://i.imgur.com/1tBrQ.jpg ... see how its not being wrapped by a <form> tag?

Comment: so how do i fix this then? im using their proprietary widget, which writes the code automatically.  When i copy and paste the longform version of the code into a regular text widget that clearly has the form tags, the result is the same as well.  Is it that wordpress is automatically stripping out the form tags or something? If so, how do i stop that from happening?

Comment: What plugin are you using? Ill check it out.